# Error: At compilation, "varargout" was determined to be a variable

Tags: matlab

The full error message reads:

> At compilation, "varargout" was determined to be a variable and this
>    variable is uninitialized.  "varargout" is also a function name and previous
>    versions of MATLAB would have called the function.
>    However, MATLAB 7 forbids the use of the same name in the same
>    context as both a function and a variable.
>
> Error in C:\Programs\COMSOL43a\mli\mphglobal.p>mphglobal (line 177)

The function call looks like this:

```
 [param_values{1:length(params)}] = mphglobal(m, params);
```

Note that `mphglobal(..)` is closed-source.

This works sometimes, but gives the error message at other times.

Comment: When you say 'at compilation', do you mean that you are compiling Matlab code into C code?

Comment: This was compiled into some Matlab-specific executable type that has `.p` extensions. I'm pretty sure it's not translated into C code. Either gets compiled into some bytecode or just encrypted so that there is no access to the proprietary source.

Comment: I posted this because the error message is misleading and it took me some time to figure out what's wrong. Might help others faced with the same error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that sometimes `params` is empty. Then the error message appears.